# Getting values of edit text error NULLPOINTER why?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I'm trying to get text from values of edit field showed on a dialog and save it in a variable.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialg);
dialog.setTitle("Title...");
dialog.show();
Button dialogButtonCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
dialogButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();}});
Button dialogButtonOK = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.OK);
//***************************************************************************
dialogButtonOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText edt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextNom);
        nom = edt1.getText().toString();
        EditText edt2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
        description = edt2.getText().toString();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead

```
 EditText edt1=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.EditTextNom);
```

you need to look in the layout that is inflated for the `Dialog`. Right now it is looking in the one that was inflated for the `Activity` and, obviously, those `View`s don't exist in that `layout`.

Comment: EditText edt1=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.EditTextNom);

thinks it work